# Why are my PHP processes consuming so much CPU?

Tags: php, redhat

This is a system running RHEL 2.6.18-348.6.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Tue May 21 16:17:08 EDT 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

This seems somewhat related, and I'm wondering if it has security implications:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%2Fsys%2Fblock%2Floop0%2Fsubsystem%2F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Has a symlink been placed giving access to my /sys/block nodes?  Maybe this is just the bots, etc crawling them?

```
top - 20:01:56 up 7 days, 21:41,  1 user,  load average: 9.53, 10.53, 11.00
Tasks: 249 total,   9 running, 237 sleeping,   1 stopped,   2 zombie
Cpu(s): 15.0%us, 78.7%sy,  0.0%ni,  3.2%id,  3.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4151512k total,  3739888k used,   411624k free,   126812k buffers
Swap:  4194296k total,  1901364k used,  2292932k free,  1532036k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13485 client3   25   0 57964  42m 6740 R 99.7  1.0 329:07.17 php
11956 client3   25   0 58104  42m 7020 R 98.0  1.0   3550:36 php
16528 client3   22   0 57960 7264 6740 R 98.0  0.2   2784:35 php
 9054 client3   25   0 57964 7280 6736 R 97.0  0.2   2610:32 php
18320 client3   25   0 57992  42m 7000 R 88.4  1.0   1025:54 php
21193 client3   25   0 57964  12m 6740 R 85.4  0.3   3711:50 php
21633 client3   25   0 57964  39m 6740 R 81.7  1.0   1215:48 php
23635 client2   15   0 52788  36m 7088 S 23.3  0.9   0:00.70 php
23633 client1   17   0     0    0    0 Z 11.6  0.0   0:00.35 php <defunct>
 3194 mysql     15   0  741m 573m 4448 S  1.7 14.2 203:10.39 mysqld
16290 tryout    34  19  2604 1020  808 R  1.7  0.0   0:11.81 gtar
21629 nobody    18   0  395m 104m 2972 S  1.3  2.6   0:03.63 httpd
```

`[~]# sudo strace -p 13485`

```
stat64("/sys/block/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop7/subsystem/ram3/subsystem/ram5/subsystem/loop2/subsystem/loop5/dev", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat64("/sys/block/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop7/subsystem/ram3/subsystem/ram5/subsystem/loop2/subsystem/loop5/holders", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/sys/block/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop7/subsystem/ram3/subsystem/ram5/subsystem/loop2/subsystem/loop5/holders", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 4
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
getdents64(4, /* 2 entries */, 32768)   = 48
getdents64(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat64("/sys/block/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop7/subsystem/ram3/subsystem/ram5/subsystem/loop2/subsystem/loop5/range", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat64("/sys/block/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop7/subsystem/ram3/subsystem/ram5/subsystem/loop2/subsystem/loop5/removable", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat64("/sys/block/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop7/subsystem/ram3/subsystem/ram5/subsystem/loop2/subsystem/loop5/size", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat64("/sys/block/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop7/subsystem/ram3/subsystem/ram5/subsystem/loop2/subsystem/loop5/slaves", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/sys/block/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop0/subsystem/loop7/subsystem/ram3/subsystem/ram5/subsystem/loop2/subsystem/loop5/slaves", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY <unfinished ...>
```

Comment: This is almost certainly an error in your web application. That should be the first thing you look at.

Comment: Michael, that's possible but it happens to multiple processes across different sites.  It is a possibility that I'll have the app writer examine though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it can always be a problem in the app itself.  That is a dev topic.

The symptom you describe can also come from script bunnies and other hackers probing you app. On one of the systems I manage, hackers are probing it 24x7 and it is a big perf hit.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your script doing recursive directory scanning (and going where it shouldn't), or it might be that your script has some exploit that somebody found. You can check which one it is by doing "lsof -p $pid" on several of them and see if it is coming from IP that is reasonable, or from suspicious foreign countries.

Whatever is the reason, you should fix your script (either making it do not descend into unwanted directories and/or fixing the exploit that allows the attacker to force it to do so)

As a stopgap measure you can set [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) in your php.ini to limit the effect of above problem with something like:

```
open_basedir = /home/:/var/www/:/tmp/:/usr/lib/php5/:/usr/share/php
```

Then php won't be able to open files outside of those directories (make sure you add all directories when your PHP modules are stored). And as you won't put "/sys" in that list, it would avoid this specific manifestation of the problem (but of course not the source of the problem in the script itself - that still needs programming work).